# Display data based on calendar

Tags: javascript, php

I wrote code to display data based on month selection. Month is changing but data is not displaying according to that. See my code once and suggest what shall I do.When clicking the next its changing the month but the data in the calendar is not displaying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="display.php">

<!--<button id="prev">-->
<input type="button" id="prev" name="prev" value="prev" />
  <input type="text" id="date" name="date" value="" 
style="border:none;" />
<input type="button" id="next" name="next" value="next" />
<!--<button id="next">-->
<script>

//document.getElementById("date").value = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10)
var today = new Date();
var mm=today.getMonth();
var yy=today.getFullYear();
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var dat=monthNames[mm]+' '+yy;
  var yyy="";
document.getElementById("date").value = dat;
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var last=document.getElementById("date").value;
  var val=last.split(" ");
  var month=val[0];
  var year=val[1];

  if(month=='January'){
    var mmm=11;
    yyy=year-1;
    var dat=monthNames[mmm]+' '+yyy;
    document.getElementById("date").value = dat ;
  }
  else {
    var index=monthNames.indexOf(month);
  var mmm=index-1;
  var dat=monthNames[mmm]+' '+year;
  document.getElementById("date").value = dat;
  }
  });
 var xxx="";
 document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click", function() {
 var next=document.getElementById("date").value;
 var val=next.split(" ");
 var month=val[0];
 var year=val[1];

 if(month=='December'){
  var mmm=0;
  xxx=++year;
  var dat=monthNames[mmm]+' '+xxx;
  document.getElementById("date").value = dat ;
 }
 else {
  var index=monthNames.indexOf(month);
 var mmm=index+1;
 var dat=monthNames[mmm]+' '+year;
 document.getElementById("date").value = dat;
 }
 });
 </script>

 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

display.php

```
<?php

 include 'config.php';
 if(isset($_POST['prev']) || isset($_POST['next']))
 {
 $monyear=$_POST['date'];
 $mnh=explode(' ',$monyear);
 $years=$mnh[1];
 $months=strtolower(substr("$mnh[0]",0,3));
 $comb=$months.'-'.$years;

 $select ="SELECT * FROM `daily_report` WHERE `reg_id`='akshaypm123' and 
 `monyr`='$comb' ";
 $res = mysqli_query($db,$select);

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
 {
 $abc=$row['monyr'];
 $count=0;
 $ab=explode('-',$abc);
 $year = $ab[1];
 $month = $ab[0];
 $mon = date("m", strtotime($month));

 $date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $mon, 1, $year);
 $daysInMonth = date("t", $date);
  $offset = date("w", $date); //for may->offset=1
 $rows = 1;

 echo "<h1 align = center> " . date("F Y", $date) . "</h1>\n";
 echo "<table align = center>";
 echo "<tbody style = 'font-family:monospace;background-color:beige; border-
  top:2 solid black'>";
 echo "\t<tr style ='height:3em;background-color:mistyrose;'><th>Sunday</th>
 <th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th>
 <th>Friday</th><th>Saturday </th></tr>";
 echo "\n\t<tr>";
 for($i = 1; $i <= $offset; $i++)
 {
    echo "<td border = 2 soild black></td>";

 }

 for($day = 1; $day <= $daysInMonth; $day++)
 {
  if( ($day + $offset - 1) % 7 == 0 && $day != 1)
 {

   echo "<tr>\n\t</tr>";
   $rows++;
  }
  
   $cba=$row['d'.$day.''];
   $time=explode('-',$cba);
        if ($cba=='leave') {
    $count +=1;
   }

  if($count>1)
  {
    switch($time[0]) {

    case 'leave':
              $bg_color = "red";
              break;
  /*  case 'absent':
          $bg_color = "red";
          break;*/

          case 'NH':
                $bg_color = "yellow";
                break;
          case $time[0]=='08:30 AM ' || $time[0]<='09:00 AM ':
                $bg_color = "honeydew";
                break;
          case $time[0]>'09:00 AM ':
                $bg_color = "orange";
                break;

        }

       }
     else {
       switch($time[0]) {

         case 'leave':
            $bg_color = "green";
         break;

        case 'NH':
              $bg_color = "yellow";
              break;
        case $time[0]=='08:30 AM ' || $time[0]<='09:00 AM ':
              $bg_color = "honeydew";
              break;
        case $time[0]>'09:00 AM ':
              $bg_color = "orange";
              break;

      }
     }
      if(($day + $offset - 1) % 7 == 0){
       echo "<td style=' width:6em; background-
       color:cornflowerblue'>&emsp;&emsp;<br></td>";
    }
      else if($time[0]!=null){
        echo "<td style=' width:10em; height:5em; text-align:center; 
      background-color:".$bg_color."'>".$cba."</td>";
      }
     else  {
       echo "<td style='background-color:red;text-align:center;'>LOP<br>
     </td>";
     }

    }

   while( ($day + $offset) <= $rows * 7)
   {

   echo "<td></td>";
   $day++;
  }


   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</tbody></table>";
  }

  }

  else{
    $disp= strtolower(date("M-Y"));
    $select ="SELECT * FROM `daily_report` WHERE `reg_id`='akshaypm123' and  
    `monyr`='$disp'";
    $res = mysqli_query($db,$select);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
    $abc=$row['monyr'];
    $count=0;
    $ab=explode('-',$abc);
    $year = $ab[1];
    $month = $ab[0];
    $mon = date("m", strtotime($month));
    $date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $mon, 1, $year);
    $daysInMonth = date("t", $date);
    $offset = date("w", $date); //for may->offset=1
    $rows = 1;

    echo "<h1 align = center> " . date("F Y", $date) . "</h1>\n";
    echo "<table align = center>";
    echo "<tbody style = 'font-family:monospace;background-color:beige; 
     border-top:2 solid black'>";
    echo "\t<tr style ='height:3em;background-color:mistyrose;'>
    <th>Sunday</th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday </th></tr>";
    echo "\n\t<tr>";
     for($i = 1; $i <= $offset; $i++)
     {
    echo "<td border = 2 soild black></td>";

      }

    for($day = 1; $day <= $daysInMonth; $day++)
    {
    if( ($day + $offset - 1) % 7 == 0 && $day != 1)
     {

     echo "<tr>\n\t</tr>";
     $rows++;
    }
     $cba=$row['d'.$day.''];
     $time=explode('-',$cba);

    if ($cba=='leave') {
    $count +=1;
    }

    if($count>1)
    {
    switch($time[0]) {

    case 'leave':
              $bg_color = "red";
              break;
          case 'NH':
                $bg_color = "yellow";
                break;
          case $time[0]=='08:30 AM ' || $time[0]<='09:00 AM ':
                $bg_color = "honeydew";
                break;
          case $time[0]>'09:00 AM ':
                $bg_color = "orange";
                break;

        }

      }
      else {
      switch($time[0]) {

       case 'leave':
            $bg_color = "green";
         break;

        case 'NH':
              $bg_color = "yellow";
              break;
        case $time[0]=='08:30 AM ' || $time[0]<='09:00 AM ':
              $bg_color = "honeydew";
              break;
        case $time[0]>'09:00 AM ':
              $bg_color = "orange";
              break;

      }
      }
       if(($day + $offset - 1) % 7 == 0){
       echo "<td style=' width:6em; background-
       color:cornflowerblue'>&emsp;&emsp;<br></td>";
     }
      else if($time[0]!=null){
        echo "<td style=' width:10em; height:5em; text-align:center; 
          background-color:".$bg_color."'>".$cba."</td>";
      }
     else  {
       echo "<td style='background-color:red;text-align:center;'>LOP<br>
             </td>";
     }

     }

    while( ($day + $offset) <= $rows * 7)
    {

     echo "<td></td>";
     $day++;
    }


     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</tbody></table>";

    } 
    } 
    ?>
```

I tried in ajax by passing date value, but it is not working.[enter image
description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qndlY.png)

Comment: There is no Ajax in your code.

Comment: Apart from it not working you might want to take a look at how HTML tables work. Yours are wrong.

Comment: @J.Litvak In this code its not there, i removed. But I tried.

Comment: I am getting data into table correctly. But I am unable to pass the data after clicking buttons. How to pass the data need to know. @kerbholz

Comment: Yet your HTML "tables" are not valid HTML. (`<td>` outside of table, `<body>` in a table, typo in `soild` etc.)